# NG0200: How to break circular dependency between standalone and non-standalone component

Tags: angular, circular-dependency, angular-standalone-components

I have two angular components inside a library I'm working on (`LibAComponent` and `LibBComponent`). `LibAComponent` is declared in `MyLibModule` and `LibBComponent` is a standalone component. Is it possible that the two components use each other in their templates?

In order for `LibAComponent` to use `LibBComponent` I imported `LibBComponent` into `MyLibModule`.
Now, if I want to use `LibAComponent` inside `LibBComponent` I have to import `MyLibModule` into `LibBComponent` which either results in a `TypeError: type is undefined` or, if i use `forwardRef`, a `NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected` error.

The Code is also availabe on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-3zybkk).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'lib-a',
  template: `a
    <ng-container *ngIf="renderChild"> 
      -> <lib-b></lib-b> 
    </ng-container>`,
})
export class LibAComponent {
  @Input()
  renderChild: boolean = false;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-b',
  template: `b 
    <ng-container *ngIf="renderChild">
      ->  <lib-a></lib-a>
    </ng-container>`,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, forwardRef(() => MyLibraryModule)],
})
export class LibBComponent {
  @Input()
  renderChild: boolean = false;
}


@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, LibBComponent],
  declarations: [LibAComponent],
  exports: [LibAComponent, LibBComponent],
})
export class MyLibraryModule {}
```